# Finding sequence limits from matrix determinants

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, integer-sequence

I have a problem whereby I want to calculate the limit of a sequence of determinants of matrices of increasing dimensions using the DiscreteLimit command. To illustrate this, I use an example with a known exact limit. Consider the following

```
f[n_] = Det[SparseArray[Table[{i, i} -> 1 + 1/n, {i, 1, n}]]];
DiscreteLimit[f[n], n -> Infinity]
```

We are really calculating $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}n{})^n$ which we know to be $e$, but running the code won't give me this. Is there any way of calculating this limit starting from the function $f$ defined as the determinant of the matrices. Thanks.

Comment: Normally I would suggest `FindSequenceFunction[]` for this, but even in your simple case, it seems to choke.

Comment: In some simple cases, you might be able to find a recurrence relationship between the determinants for different values of `n`